# AspNetCore use cookie and bearer together, and make Authorize attribute to use both by default

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth

I have application where its using Cookie and Bearer token. Since i dont want update each Authorize by providing a schemas I did rewrite default schemas:

```
   services
            .AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                            "Identity.Application")
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();
                });
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddExternalAuthProviders(Configuration)
                .AddFlymarkOpenIdConnectServer()
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/LogIn";
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = OnRedirectToLogin;
                })
                .AddOAuthValidation(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    o=>o.Events.OnCreateTicket = OnCreateTicket);
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
            {
                config.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToLogin = OnRedirectToLogin
                };
            });
```

I thought that if I add **CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme** then it will work but cookies are not working untill I add **Identity.Application**

So my question is why its not working or where is constant to use instead of hardcoded string

Comment: you will have to write your own custom authentication that verifies both

Comment: here is a sample custom auth. https://github.com/neville-nazerane/netcore-jwt-sample/blob/master/website/Services/TokenAuthScheme.cs. This does JWT auth in a little manual way, however I remember there being a way to you can call an auth scheme's challenge

Comment: @NevilleNazerane well its working fine, my question was basically why this  CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme is not working but Pinpoint answered in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981910/aspnetcore-bearer-auth-use-user-inside-of-middleware/53982812

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core Identity uses its own instances of the cookie authentication handler, magically registered for you when you call `services.AddIdentity()`.

As you figured out, these instances don't use the default scheme name but a name that starts with the `Identity.` prefix.

In your code, you're basically registering a new cookie handler instance with the default scheme name. But since nothing in your code uses it to issue cookies, it can't validate anything and will always return unauthenticated tickets, which is why it doesn't work until you add the magical `Identity.Application`, which corresponds to the main cookie handler instance used by ASP.NET Core Identity.

The constant you're looking for is in [`IdentityConstants`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/src/Identity/IdentityConstants.cs).

Note: be extremely careful before adding a default policy that accepts both authentication cookies and bearer tokens, as your app might be vulnerable to CSRF if it doesn't use antiforgery (which is normally the case when developing an API).